# jekyll serve is not serving in localhost and showing other page

Tags: jekyll

I have install **jekyll** and have used it in my blog creation.
But when i type the command

```
        jekyll serve
```

It show an address 0.0.0.0:4000
Which is not local host.
Also,The address shows a blank page instead of my blog.
Help me to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 1):

`jekyll serve` always shows :

```
Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000
```

It doesn't mean that the website will be displayed on this IP address : it **isn't** an IP address! It means "server, listen on every available network interface". 127.0.0.1 *is* a network interface, so the server should listen to it.

That is to say `localhost:4000` (or 127.0.0.1) should display your website. If not, the problem isn't related to this strange 0.0.0.0:4000.

Answer (score 0):

With using `0.0.0.0` you able to access it from another device using your machine IP address in the same network.